# Google Cloud - endpoint latency monitoring

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-endpoints

Is there a way how to setup proper monitoring and alerting for API endpoints in Google Cloud? I can see median and percentiles latency here: https://console.cloud.google.com/endpoints/api/
But I want to setup alerting for it. For example, if latency median is above 100ms for a 1h I will receive an email. I've been trying Stackdriver as well, even premium version, but no luck. I've been able to plot latencies, but not to setup alerting.

Any advices please?

Edit:
I've just found out Apigee option to deploy APIs with monitoring included. Do you have any experience with it?

Answer (score 1):

Stackdriver doesn't support alerting on distribution metrics yet. Endpoints uses distribution metrics for latency. This is why you're not able to set up alerting for Endpoints latency. Stackdriver is working on supporting distribution metrics. When this is out, you will be able to set up alerting for Endpoints latency.